# Why does my function return nothing? C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

Here is the code:

```
public static int foo( int a)
{
    int result = 0; 

    for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; i < 2*a; j += 2)
        {
          result = result + i; 
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

The following input..

```
Console.WriteLine(foo(2));
Console.ReadLine();
```

returns nothing.I really think the code should work. I don't get any error so what do I need to fix ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint.  Step through the code.  You have all the tools you need to solve this.

Comment: I doubt it does not returns nothing, maybe it does not returns what you expected, but it returns something.

Comment: change i < 2*a to j < 2*a to prevent the endless inner loop

Comment: @OrelEraki Had the same thought but I need to change this line: for (int j = 1; i < 2*a; j += 2) . Then we will get a result like expected.

Answer (score 2):

Because this:

```
for (int j = 1; i < 2*a; j += 2)
```

Never does anything to change `i`, hence it's in an infinite loop because it always remains 1.

You probably ment:

```
for (int j = 1; j < 2*a; j += 2)
```

Comment: Oh god you are right. Sometimes I overlook things like this. Thank you sir